# Validar rutas por usuario

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

soy relativamente nuevo en este "mundo" y no se si esta pregunta haya surgido más veces y si es así para un caso muy específico, pero procederé a documentar mi duda.

Estoy construyendo una especie de tienda web, en mi caso estoy usando Express como framework web, y MongoDB como base de datos, hasta aquí todo bien, pero cuando llega el momento de añadir productos a la tienda, mi idea principal y en la que no pensé mucho en un primer momento fue crear un formulario con una ruta POST

El problema aquí llega cuando a esta ruta, solo debería de entrar un usuario con privilegios o algo por el estilo, he pensado y buscado en diferentes alternativas, he encontrado algunos módulos de express pero la mayoría están en desuso o deprecados.

También he pensado en el uso de algún middleware que hasta ahora es la opción que veo mas factible, pero no se me ocurre la manera de validar si un usuario es un usuario con privilegios o un usuario "raso", y que en caso de que uno de estos usuarios rasos accediera a la ruta GET del formulario se le deniegue el permiso o en todo caso se le deniegue el envió del formulario por POST.

Si alguien ha tenido un problema similar y ha conseguido solucionarlo agradecería la ayuda :)

Aquí adjunto la ruta POST de la que hable anteriormente:

```
export const newProduct = async (req, res) => {
    const productData = productSchm(req.body);

    let errorProducts = [];

    const productNameQuery = await productSchm.find({
        "name": productData.name
    }, {
        "_id": 0,
        "name": 1
    });

    const productURLQuery = await productSchm.find({
        "URLName": productData.URLName
    }, {
        "_id": 0,
        "URLName": 1
    });

    // Recorremos el array que nos devuelve la consulta a la base de datos, y los convertimos a un objeto
    // esto por que el parametro key, es el objeto ya independiente del array, asi nuestra consulta
    // ahora es el objeto que estaba contenido en el array
    productNameQuery.map(key => {
        productNameQuery = key;
    });
    
    // Convertimos el valor de URLName a minusculas y seguidamente volvemos a cambiar el valor del URLName haciendo que los huecos en blanco
    // queden reemplazados por una barrabaja en su lugar
    Object.keys(productData).map(() => {
        productData.URLName = productData.URLName.toLowerCase();
        productData.URLName = productData.URLName.replace(/ /g,'-');
    });

    // Si el producto ya existe por nombre, se deniga el nuevo producto, por que ya existe
    if (productData.name === productNameQuery.name) {
        errorProducts.push({text: `El producto ya existe por que el nombre es el mismo que el del producto: <a href="">${productData.name}</a>`});
    };

    /**
     * * El precio del producto a veces puede ser 0 pero por defecto se denegara la creacion
     * * del producto para evitar posibles problemas
     * ! Esta regla podra ser modificada si se necesita crear algun producto con valor 0
     */
    if (productData.price <= 0) {
        errorProducts.push({text: "El producto no puede tener un valor menor a 0, esto podria ocasionar fallos en la base de datos"});
    };

    // Si hay errores se muestran esos errores por pantalla
    if (errorProducts.length > 0) {
        res.render("add_Products", {errorProducts, productURLQuery});
    } else {
        await productData.save();
        console.log("new product saved:", productData.name);
        setTimeout(() => {
            res.redirect("/products");
        }, 1500);
    };
};
```

con su respectiva ruta GET:

```
export const renderNewProduct = (req, res) => {
    res.render("add_Products");
};
```

Comment: Si, puedes solucionarlo con un middleware. Ahi (según tu metodo de autenticación), validas el usuario que está intentando acceder, y si no es del tipo que esperas no lo dejas seguir. Que tipo de autenticacion estás manejando?

Comment: Por ahora no he implementado autentificación, ya que me tope con el problema y antes de hacer nada prefiero pensar en al solución que le podría dar. De igual modo, aprovechando que estoy usando mongoose como ODM, podría añadir un campo al esquema de los usuarios, y mas tarde validarlo con un middleware como me comentaste no se si haya una manera mas eficiente, de igual forma. Gracias :) @Pipe

Comment: Si, como lo dices está correcto